# [c++][cygwin][gcc] Boost Filesystem linking from DLL via BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cygwin

I've very simple piece of code witch utilize Libboost filesystem to check if file exist or not. Additionally I want to use libboost as dll library, not static one. Here you have what I written few minutes ago:

```
void Hex2bin::convert(string filename, vector<uint8_t>* decodedBytes) {
 const path fname(filename);    // from boost::filesystem

 if (exists(fname)) {
    ;
 }
 else {
    throw new EFileDoesntExist;
 }

}
```

Unfortunately when I remove -lboost_filesystem from linker settings and add macro BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK globally in Eclipse configuration I get only such linker error as below:

/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:446: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

Source file compiles without any warning. When I revert back to -lboost_filesystem everything works OK, but I assume that then library is statically linked to EXE file.  Have anybody any idea what is going wrong? Or maybe I have wrong understanding how libboost can be linked?

Answer (score 0):

No.  You still need to specify`-lboost_filesystem` even if the library is a shared object rather than a static library.  In fact, most linkers will *prefer* to link against a shared object rather than a .a if both are present (there are ways to change this if necessary).

Use `ldd` to see the shared libraries an executable is linked against.

Comment: Hi. You are right. I just checked ldd on my exe and library is linked from dll :)

Answer (score 0):

Only Windows (specifically MSVC++) supports "auto-linking" with Boost. On Linux, you'd either link against `libboost_filesystem.so` or `libboost_filesystem.a`, but in either case you need to link explicitly.

Comment: But you would link against both with `-lboost_filesystem` and the linker would use whichever it can find.

Comment: Thank You for quick answer. I'm using Cygwin64 under Windows 7 x64, but according to Martin Bonner reply problem seems to be resolved